# Handlebar.js if statement is not working

Tags: backbone.js, if-statement, handlebars.js

I added a combobox in a list-table template,and ı want to render combobox depending on the database in my model, so whats wrong? Help please..

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="listItemTmpl">
<tr>                             
    <td>{{partNo}}</td>
    <td>
         <select name="selectCombo" id="selectCombo">
                {{#each chks}}
                <option value='{{myModel.id}}' {{#if(this.id==myModel1.status)}}selected{{/if}}>{{myModel1.name}}</option>
                {{/each}}
            </select>
    </td>
</tr>

</script>
```

ı have two model;
one is,

```
 myModel1=Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:url,
    defaults:{
      name:"",
      status:""
  }
 });
```

other is;

```
myModel=Backbone.Model.extend({
  url:url,
  defaults:{

  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, that's not how handlebars works. The expression `{{#if(this.id==myModel1.status)}}` is not a valid handlebars if-block.

Handlebars is a semantic, declarative templating engine. It doesn't support arbitrary javascript expressions. The only thing you can check with the `#if` block is, whether something is truthy (not `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `""` or `[]`).

The preferred way would be to evaluate the condition before rendering the template, and pass the result to the template using the viewmodel. In your case, you could add a `isSelected` property to each of the the objects in the `chks` array, and simply evaluate it in the template with

```
{{#if isSelected}}selected{{/if}}
```

See the [handlebars.js documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for examples on how to use handlebars.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should use an `isSelected` flag and [fencliff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802519/479863) covers that. However, sometimes adding an extra flag isn't a reasonable option and if that's the case, you can add your `{{#ifeq}}` helper. Something simple like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function(a, b, block) {
    return a == b ? block() : block.inverse();
});
```

and then in the template:

```
<option value='{{myModel.id}}' {{#ifeq id myModel1.status}}selected{{/ifeq}}>{{myModel1.name}}</option>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/rsyv9/

Comment: I thought about suggesting this also, but I felt it goes against handelbars' declarative, logic-less grain. There are plenty of templating frameworks that provide ability to define logic, if one is into that sort of thing. There's one baked into underscore.js, which OP is already using.

Comment: @fencliff: There's always an *it depends*. And mixing two template engines is nasty.

Comment: @fa. I'd go with fencliff's approach for most cases, adding an `ifeq` helper is more useful when things get complicated and the JavaScript and template can't be as tightly coupled as Handlebars would like.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update. The latest version of Handlebars used  block.fn()  rather than  block(). May throw errors otherwise.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function(a, b, block) {
    return a == b ? block.fn() : block.inverse();
});
```